# Android notifications get service that started the notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications, android-service

I have a service that performs an operation after a certain delay. I want to show a notification when the service is started, and when the notification is clicked it cancels the operation. No UI, all done in the background. The service is started on boot by a broadcast receiver.

Also ideally I want to update the notification every 1 sec to show the remaining time.

```
... start operation thread and call thread.sleep(delay)
... create notification builder (nBuilder)
            try { // example assume delay = 30 seconds
                for (int sec = 30; sec >= 0; --sec) {
                    nBuilder.setContentText("Applying settings in " + sec + ", Click to cancel");
                    mNotifyMgr.notify(0x01, nBuilder.build());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

how can I break this loop when the notification is clicked? This code is in my service. As far as i know the only way to respond to click is to set a pending intent, but how can I use this intent to break the loop and cancel the operation in my service?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks david, but I've found a simpler solution

I just made a member reference to my thread and created a pending intent for the service with a cancel flag set, and it retrieves the same service instance so i'm able to interrupt the thread.

Not sure I did a great job explaining the question but I figured why not share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service`. When the notification is clicked, use a `PendingIntent` that will trigger your `BroadcastReceiver`. When the `onReceive()` method in your `BroadcastReceiver` is run, it can cancel the operation in your `Service`.